# Why isn't my query string parameter being passed to my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newbie question

URL:

```
/categories/new?parent_id=6
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @category = Category.new( :parent_id => params[ :parent_id ] )
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for( @category ) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
<% end %>
```

Source of the page:

```
<input id="category_parent_id" name="category[parent_id]" type="hidden" />
```

Why isn't the value being passed through?

**EDIT:** I realized after that I didn't have `:parent_id` as part of my `attr_accessible` in my model Category. Everything's working as it should now. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: We need a little bit more to go with here Bill. However give this a try and let us know. Category.new(params[ :parent_id ]) and add <%= debug(params) %> in the view and see the output.

Comment: I think you should check nested_attributes. You may need that one to make you code more structured. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1  http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Sorry about that @Ceilingfish, that was a typo in the question. The code's correct.

Comment: @ChuckJHardy
Here's the output:

    --- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
    action: new
    parent_id: "6"
    controller: categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED after @Ceilingfish wise remark

Try this:

```
<%= form_for( @category ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => params[:parent_id] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get an exception with a message: `undefined method 'merge' for "6":String`

Comment: I think he means `<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => params[:parent_id] %>`. However it should be automagically filled in if the object has the appropriate attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the value from a hidden field in the form, but it is being sent as a query parameter in the url.